# Meshlab advice. Is this software for me?

Tags: point-clouds, meshlab

I would like to create a mesh from pointcloud data. I am able to get pointcloud data from a Faro laser scanner.  I can save it as .xyz, .dat, .asc formats. I can't afford to buy Geomagic wrap and would like to know if I can get a quality mesh with Meshlab. The meshes I make with my current software are not very smooth. The overlaps of the scanner make alot of noise. Can anyone point me in the direction of a workflow in Meshlab to convert an .xyz or other file type into an .stl or .obj
Here's the best I can do with wrap trial:
[first attempt with a Wrap trial software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb0lJ.jpg)

I can also supply the file to anyone who would like to take my .xyz file and use it to show the workflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that meshlab can absolutely cover your needs.

You can find many surface reconstruction methods under:

`Filters` -> `Remeshing, simplification and Reconstruction`

The best results will most likely be given by the [`Screened Poisson Surface Reconstructiom`](http://hhoppe.com/proj/screenedpoisson/) option. Click on `Help` to get info about the avaliable parameters.

In addition meshlab have a lot of options for cleaning and basically for almost anything you want to do with meshes (and it has some point cloud features aswell).

Check the [Support page](http://www.meshlab.net/#support).

Comment: David,Thanks for your help.  I'm glad you think that this will work for me.  I am trying several things, but I still can't get visible points on my screen.  I tried the .txt file and use ; as the separator, deleting the header.  But the point's are not visible on the screen.  Can you help, or do you know of a tutorial that helps with this?

Answer (score 0):

David, Thanks for your reply.  I'm glad to hear you think it's a good choice.  I will update once I've figured out a workflow. This is what I accomplished with David software, but it took hours...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbqHh.jpg)